# How can I bulk/batch transcribe wav files using python?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, speech-recognition, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

im trying to use my python app to transcribe multiple files in a folder and speed up the process.
At present I am able to do it one file at a time -

```
####RUN THIS PART FIRST#########
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
import threading
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
import pandas as pd
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('xxyyzz')

service = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)
service.set_service_url('https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com')

models = service.list_models().get_result()
#print(json.dumps(models, indent=2))

model = service.get_model('en-US_BroadbandModel').get_result()
#print(json.dumps(model, indent=2))

# This is the name of the file u need to change below
with open(join(dirname('__file__'), 'Call 8.wav'),
          'rb') as audio_file:
#    print(json.dumps(
    output = service.recognize(
    audio=audio_file,
    speaker_labels=True,
    content_type='audio/wav',
    #timestamps=True,
    #word_confidence=True,
    inactivity_timeout = -1,
    model='en-US_NarrowbandModel',
    continuous=True).get_result(),
    indent=2
  ############END################################  

# get data to a csv
########################RUN THIS PART SECOND#####################################
df0 = pd.DataFrame([i for elts in output for alts in elts['results'] for i in alts['alternatives']])

df1 = pd.DataFrame([i for elts in output for i in elts['speaker_labels']])

list(df0.columns) 
list(df1.columns) 
df0 = df0.drop(["timestamps"], axis=1)
df1 = df1.drop(["final"], axis=1)
df1 = df1.drop(['confidence'],axis=1)
test3 = pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=1)
#sentiment
transcript = test3['transcript']
transcript = transcript.dropna()
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
text = transcript
scores = []
for txt in text:
    vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(txt)
    scores.append(vs)
data = pd.DataFrame(text, columns= ['Text'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame(scores)
final_dataset= pd.concat([data,data2], axis=1)
test4 = pd.concat([test3,final_dataset], axis=1)
test4 = test4.drop(['Text'],axis=1)
test4.rename(columns={'neg':'Negative'}, 
                 inplace=True)
test4.rename(columns={'pos':'Positive'}, 
                 inplace=True)
test4.rename(columns={'neu':'Neutral'}, 
                 inplace=True)

# This is the name of the output csv file
test4.to_csv("Call 8.csv")
```

How can i do this to transcribe multiple files in a folder instead of one file at a time?I can run this script multiple times but i want to automate it such that it picks up wav files from a folder and runs it. lets say I have 15 audio wav files in my folder C:\Python. I want to make it an automated process where it will run the script and get 15 csvs. 1 for each with their resp. outputs. right now this script works but have to manually run it for each wav file to get each wavs output csv.

Also,as a second question(sorry!), is there a way to speed up the transcription? breakup the wav files into smaller segments and send to watson but it didnt work. My reference was - (https://github.com/freelanceastro/interview-transcriber)

Comment: Add what you have tried, e.g. have you send multiple requests in parallel? If yes, what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: I havent sent in parallel. How can I do it for multiple files in a folder?

Comment: Python has some multi-processing / async-processing modules and features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have something:

```
import os
import json
import time
# import threading
from pathlib import Path

import concurrent.futures

# from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

import pandas as pd

# Replace with your api key.
my_api_key = "abc123"

# You can add a directory path to Path() if you want to run
# the project from a different folder at some point.
directory = Path().absolute()


authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(my_api_key)

service = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)
service.set_service_url('https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com')
# I used this URL.
# service.set_service_url('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api') 


models = service.list_models().get_result()
#print(json.dumps(models, indent=2))

model = service.get_model('en-US_BroadbandModel').get_result()
#print(json.dumps(model, indent=2))



# get data to a csv
########################RUN THIS PART SECOND#####################################


def process_data(json_data, output_path):

    print(f"Processing: {output_path.stem}")

    cols = ["transcript", "confidence"]

    dfdata = [[t[cols[0]], t[cols[1]]] for r in json_data.get('results') for t in r.get("alternatives")]

    df0 = pd.DataFrame(data = dfdata, columns = cols)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(json_data.get("speaker_labels")).drop(["final", "confidence"], axis=1)


    # test3 = pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=1)
    test3 = pd.merge(df0, df1, left_index = True, right_index = True)


    # sentiment
    print(f"Getting sentiment for: {output_path.stem}")
    transcript = test3["transcript"]
    transcript.dropna(inplace=True)

    analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    text = transcript
    scores = [analyzer.polarity_scores(txt) for txt in text]

    # data = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ["Text"])
    data = transcript.to_frame(name="Text")
    data2 = pd.DataFrame(scores)


    # final_dataset= pd.concat([data, data2], axis=1)
    final_dataset = pd.merge(data, data2, left_index = True, right_index = True)

    # test4 = pd.concat([test3, final_dataset], axis=1)
    test4 = pd.merge(test3, final_dataset, left_index = True, right_index = True)

    test4.drop("Text", axis=1, inplace=True)

    test4.rename(columns = {
            "neg": "Negative",
            "pos": "Positive",
            "neu": "Neutral",
            }, inplace=True)

    # This is the name of the output csv file
    test4.to_csv(output_path, index = False)


def process_audio_file(filename, output_type = "csv"):

    audio_file_path = directory.joinpath(filename)

    # Update output path to consider `output_type` parameter.
    out_path = directory.joinpath(f"{audio_file_path.stem}.{output_type}")

    print(f"Current file: '{filename}'")

    with open(audio_file_path, "rb") as audio_file:
        data = service.recognize(
                audio = audio_file,
                speaker_labels = True,
                content_type = "audio/wav",
                inactivity_timeout = -1,
                model = "en-US_NarrowbandModel",
                continuous = True,
            ).get_result()

    print(f"Speech-to-text complete for: '{filename}'")

    # Return data and output path as collection.
    return [data, out_path]


def main():
    print("Running main()...")

    # Default num. workers == min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4)
    n_workers = os.cpu_count() + 2

    # Create generator for all .wav files in folder (and subfolders).
    file_gen = directory.glob("**/*.wav")

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = n_workers) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(process_audio_file, f) for f in file_gen}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            pkg = future.result()
            process_data(*pkg)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(f"Program to process audio files has started.")

    t_start = time.perf_counter()

    main()

    t_stop = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Done! Processing completed in {t_stop - t_start} seconds.")
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. I tested it on 3 wav files and it worked in 55 seconds even though the total amount of minutes of those wav files amounted to over 4 minutes.Approving this answer as it satisfies both halves of the question.

Comment: Thanks!  That was pretty fun.  This was probably my second time using IBM Watson, first time for speech-to-text.  Definitely an interesting platform that I might have to look into more.

Comment: Mark. yes I prefer Watson to AWS and Gcloud. Its a cost friendly API too. Thanks for your input! My next mission is to improve the accuracy of the model. They do let you customize based on what your business needs are!

Comment: Hey Mark, i have a couple of questions(I can post this as a new question on SO if you like) - 1) I am trying to get this script to work in a shiny app and want to only return a dataframe, so users have the option to download the csv instead of automatically generating one. How could i change the script to do that? 2) If i did not want to transcribe multiple files and just wanted to do it one a time like my original app, but wanted to add your speed enhancements so it can transcribe faster for even a single file, what should i change in my original code?. Truly appreciate your help

Comment: Hi.  I'm not super familiar with Shiny (the R library, right?), but if you can run a subprocess (command line) script from Shiny, you should be able to execute this script and make it available somehow.  Possibly local storage?  Wherever the script outputs the csv file to is where you'd direct the link.

Comment: For the second question, I think that might be limited to Watson's capabilities and the Internet connection.  If it takes ~30 seconds to process a file, but you can do multiple files at once, then the total time should still be ~30 seconds.  But, this answer might also help out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48552764/2847946

Comment: Hey Mark,thanks for your response. i think i wasnt able to communicate my questions well. for the first question. Lets forget about the Rshiny app for now. My question is how will i return the output as a dataframe and not a csv. I just want the final output to be in a dataframe format without writing it to a csv. For my second question, its not about the speed it runs at a great speed already(thanks to you :) I meant, how could i add your speed enhancements to my original app, where i am not transcribing batches(multiple files), but one wav at a time.

Comment: Mark, also, please recommend if i can do to make my transcription more accurate.

Comment: Hi.  I think that if you just change `test4.to_csv(output_path, index = False)` to `return test4` in the `process_data()`  function, then that should output the complete dataframe.

Comment: I might still not understand the second question.  Do you mean just a more-efficient `process_data()` function?  If so, there's some decent documentation on the Pandas website about enhancements and optimizations.  Using `Numba` and `eval()` methods are pretty good starting points.  Link -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running this script multiple times? you could write a wrapper that launches this script in a subprocess kinda like this:

```
import subprocess
import sys

processes = []
for _ in range(5):
    processes.append(subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/path/to/script.py"]))

# now wait for them to finish
for process in processes:
    process.wait()
```

Comment: I can run this script multiple times but i want to automate it such that it picks up wav files from a folder and runs it. lets say i have 15 audio files in my folder C:\Python. I want to make it an automated process where it will run the script and get 15 csvs. 1 for each with their resp. outputs. right now this script works but have to manually run it for each wav file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to find all .wav files in a directory and process each in turn.

```py
import os

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith('.wav'):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as audio_file:
```

You could even extend it so that it keeps running and only processes new files.

Comment: Hey chugts,excuse my elementary question but where inside my existing script do i put your code exactly to test it?

Comment: line up the `with open(` with the `with open(` in your code.

Comment: I tried this approach but it still only gives an output of 1 csv. I tested with 5 audio files and i received only 1 csv. I should be received 5 csvs with each wavs transcription output in each csv.

Comment: Most likely because you are writing to the same csv file each time.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on improving accuracy of transcription. im currently on the lite plan and this is a base model

Answer (score 0):

You can just try to turn your code into a function, scanning for all files with the .wav extension in your current directory (using `os` like some previously mentioned or `glob`), and calling this function for every file. It would result in something like this:

```
####RUN THIS PART FIRST#########
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
import threading
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
import pandas as pd
import glob

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('xxyyzz')

service = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)
service.set_service_url('https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com')

models = service.list_models().get_result()
#print(json.dumps(models, indent=2))

model = service.get_model('en-US_BroadbandModel').get_result()
#print(json.dumps(model, indent=2))

def transcribe(infile, service):
    # This is the name of the file u need to change below
    with open(infile,'rb') as audio_file:
    #    print(json.dumps(
        output = service.recognize(
        audio=audio_file,
        speaker_labels=True,
        content_type='audio/wav',
        #timestamps=True,
        #word_confidence=True,
        inactivity_timeout = -1,
        model='en-US_NarrowbandModel',
        continuous=True).get_result(),
        indent=2
      ############END################################  

    # get data to a csv
    ########################RUN THIS PART SECOND#####################################
    df0 = pd.DataFrame([i for elts in output for alts in elts['results'] for i in alts['alternatives']])

    df1 = pd.DataFrame([i for elts in output for i in elts['speaker_labels']])

    list(df0.columns) 
    list(df1.columns) 
    df0 = df0.drop(["timestamps"], axis=1)
    df1 = df1.drop(["final"], axis=1)
    df1 = df1.drop(['confidence'],axis=1)
    test3 = pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=1)
    #sentiment
    transcript = test3['transcript']
    transcript = transcript.dropna()
    from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
    analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    text = transcript
    scores = []
    for txt in text:
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(txt)
        scores.append(vs)
    data = pd.DataFrame(text, columns= ['Text'])
    data2 = pd.DataFrame(scores)
    final_dataset= pd.concat([data,data2], axis=1)
    test4 = pd.concat([test3,final_dataset], axis=1)
    test4 = test4.drop(['Text'],axis=1)
    test4.rename(columns={'neg':'Negative'}, 
                     inplace=True)
    test4.rename(columns={'pos':'Positive'}, 
                     inplace=True)
    test4.rename(columns={'neu':'Neutral'}, 
                     inplace=True)

    # This is the name of the output csv file
    test4.to_csv(infile[:-4] + ".csv")

for i in glob.glob("*.wav"):
    transcribe(i, service)
```

Comment: To make @hartville-zillow happy, you should update this to look in the same directory as `__file__`. I think you also need an `*` before `.wav` in the file search. And it would probably be a good idea to only replace `.wav` with `.csv` at the end of the file name when saving, rather than replacing everywhere in the filename (which will mess up filenames like `"my.big.wave.file.wav"`).

Comment: Oh yes the `*` was definitely missed by accident. Also, good suggestions! I will implement them.

Comment: Hi @Charbelabidaher thanks for your answer. I tried running the script u posted and it ran successfully without error. However, I do not see any output csv files in the directory i used to transcribe wav files from. there is no output

Comment: @hartvillezillow could you try running this edited code again?

Comment: Hey @Charbelabidaher it works! thank you so much. I marked it correct. Any idea on how to solve the second part of the question. would really appreciate it. P.S took me a while to respond because it is taking that long to transcribe

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! I will attempt to find ways to make it faster by sending requests is parallel as suggested in other comments, however am I not sure on how successful that can be.

Comment: @Charbelabidaher do you have any suggestions to improve accuracy of transcribed words?